# How to get most recent build of Windows 10 with integrated updates in an installer package / media?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-installation

I've been having a terrible time with some users who want to upgrade to `Windows 10`. 95% of the time the upgrade goes fine and all is well... Then about 20% of those upgrades have an earth-shattering experience when updates automatically run anywhere from hours to a day or so later wherein the system will no longer boot properly.

The booting issues are varied.  *Probably about 50% of the time* we can execute something like:

```
bootrec /scanos 
bootrec /rebuildbcd 
bootrec /fixmbr 
bootrec /fixboot
```

or

```
chkdsk /f c:
bcdboot c:\windows # Where `c` is whatever drive where Windoze is installed
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
bootrec /scanos
```

But then there are the other 50% of the times... Nothing short of a reinstall / restore seems to do it.

It seems that some of the updates or cumulative updates are helping to resolve this, *but my question is*:

***How does always keep the installation media for Windows 10 up-to-date to the most current build with all present updates integrated?***

I believe that this can help to ameliorate some of these problems, but someone such as myself needs them on a USB thumb drive or such vs going through the Windows {7, 8.1} -> Windows 10 upgrade process.

Comment: There is only one build ( 10240 ) of Windows 10 that has been released.  That can be downloaded by using the Media Creation Tool located on the appropriate website.  Of course the process of using this tool vs using Windows Update to install Windows 10 is identical to one another.

Comment: So you're saying there is no slipstream builder at the moment for Windows 10 that integrates updates into the installer from Microsoft, correct? I was hoping to hear that the `Media Creation Tool` does that, but I hadn't found evidence that it does.

Comment: You can create those slipstream .iso(s) yourself in an identical way they have been done in the past.  Threshold 2 is only weeks away from being released, likely at the end of November, if reality has not changed the leaked schedule.  `Threshold 2` would be the next time Microsoft would update the .ISO for obvious reasons.

Comment: Well that's good to know, but it makes me wonder a bit more about one more point. On initial update function from the install medium, does it actually download updates and self-slipstream them for the upgrade?

Comment: **The windows installer has done that since forever.**

Comment: Good to know with certainty. I have actually seen mixed results with post install updates and so I have never really been sure on this, even as of the late Windows 10 installs.